# how to remove the exception, System.InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#

code is given below

```
Queue<int> queXpTrackerX = new Queue<int>(10);
Queue<int> queXpTrackerY = new Queue<int>(10);       

if (iCounterForXpTrack < 10)
{
    queXpTrackerX.Enqueue(X);
    queXpTrackerY.Enqueue(Y);
    iCounterForXpTrack++;
}//End IF
else
{
    queXpTrackerX.Dequeue();
    queXpTrackerY.Dequeue();
    queXpTrackerX.Enqueue(X);
    queXpTrackerY.Enqueue(Y);
}//End else

for (int indexXp = 0; indexXp < iCounterForXpTrack; indexXp++)
{
    gXpTracker.DrawEllipse(Pens.Cyan, queXpTrackerX.ElementAt(indexXp) , queXpTrackerY.ElementAt(indexXp), 5, 5);
}//end for
```

Comment: Please don't write things like '//end if' and '//end for' at the end of blocks. It clutters the code and it isn't needed to understand what is going on. Plus it's not compile checked. Even if those comments are there I won't believe them without checking it for myself.

Comment: Can you give us the message of the exception? InvalidOperationException is widely used throughout the .NET Framework.

Comment: I'd guess from the code that it is 'Queue empty.'

Comment: @Mark, what if I asked you, "Please don't prefix locals with an underscore, I don't like it"? (pretending you do prefix them).

Comment: You have to admit that writing VB code comments in C# code is crazy, at least underscores in member variables can be refactored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the most likely cause for you InvalidOperationException is trying to Dequeue from a queue when it is empty. Did you have the exception message? Is it 'Queue empty.'?

This can happen if your `iCounterForXpTrack` becomes out of sync with the number of elements in the queue. It would be better to just ask the queue directly to avoid this possible error:

```
    if (queXpTrackerX.Count < 10)
    {
        queXpTrackerX.Enqueue(X);
        queXpTrackerY.Enqueue(Y);
    }
    else
    {
        queXpTrackerX.Dequeue();
        queXpTrackerY.Dequeue();
        queXpTrackerX.Enqueue(X);
        queXpTrackerY.Enqueue(Y);
    }
```

A possible reason that your code fails is if you initialized `iCounterForXpTrack` to 10 thinking that `new Queue<int>(10)` creates a queue that starts with 10 elements. This is not the case. The queue is initially empty. Providing the capacity to the queue constructor is just a performance optimization and is not strictly needed.

Another issue with your code: instead of having two queues, one for x and one for y, you should use some sort of Point class and a `Queue<Point>`. This simplifies the code and eliminates possible errors from the two queues becoming out of sync.